# Why does my 3DS XL's 3D slider affect the volume?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, hardware

When I try to change the volume it doesn't change and stays at full volume, but when I turn the 3D on it quiets down for some reason.  How can I fix it and do I need replacements?

Comment: That...definitely doesn't sound normal. But I don't have a 3DS, so I can't dispute that.

Comment: My 3DS XL doesn't have this problem.  Incidentally, volume slider is on the left side of the system, network switch is on the right, and 3D slider is to the front right of the top screen.

Comment: I know about where the switches are, they are in two different places but the two somehow are messing with each other nonetheless.

Comment: How long have you had it? It could be a battery/power issue

Comment: Around 2-3 years.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would cause that is your battery dying, and even that's just a wild guess.

Comment: Based on the repair guides on iFixIt, the 3D slider and the Volume rocker are close enough to each other to be a possible issue, but not enough to actually cause any problems.  Based on your experiences, it seems like there might be a short on the board, (or a defect) that's causing the 3D slider to affect sound, but preventing the sound slider from doing anything.